# Selenium: Website footer testing not proceeding in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Wrote a test script recently in Selenium for testing the footer on our website that continues to fail presenting this error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (410, 4382)
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)
```

However, when running the same script snippet in FireFox and Safari the tests proceed without issue. I'm now confused as to what is causing the issue to continue seeing as the test runs in FireFox and Safari without issue. Was there something Chrome-specific I missed? Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the function currently running through the test.

```
def check_footer(driver, url):
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
cookie_banner = driver.find_element_by_name("accept-cookies")
cookie_banner.click()

time.sleep(2)

footer_careers = driver.find_element_by_name("footer_careers") 
print(footer_careers.get_attribute("outerHTML"))

time.sleep(1)

footer_careers.click()

time.sleep(3)

footer_contact = driver.find_element_by_name("footer_contact") 
print(footer_contact.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
footer_contact.click()

time.sleep(3)

footer_eula = driver.find_element_by_name("footer_eula") 
print(footer_eula.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
footer_eula.click()

time.sleep(3)

footer_privacy = driver.find_element_by_name("footer_privacy") 
print(footer_privacy.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
footer_privacy.click()

time.sleep(3)

footer_terms = driver.find_element_by_name("footer_terms") 
print(footer_terms.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
footer_terms.click()

time.sleep(3)

footer_about = driver.find_element_by_name("footer_about") 
print(footer_about.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
footer_about.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens with the selenium if the element is not in the visible area of page. I suggest trying clicking using javascript, e.g:

```
cookie_banner = driver.find_element_by_name("accept-cookies")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", cookie_banner)
```

or scroll page to your required element before clicking:

```
cookie_banner = driver.find_element_by_name("accept-cookies")
driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'auto',
        block: 'center',
        inline: 'center'
        });""", cookie_banner)
cookie_banner.click()
```